# Some spark-submit config options not reflected in k8s pod

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm using `spark-submit` to create a spark driver pod on my k8s cluster. When I run

```sh
bin/spark-submit 
--master k8s://https://my-cluster-url:443
--deploy-mode cluster 
--name spark-test 
--class com.my.main.Class 
--conf spark.executor.instances=3 
--conf spark.kubernetes.allocation.batch.size=3 
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=my-namespace 
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullSecrets=my-cr-secret 
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always 
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.my-pvc.mount.path=/var/service/src/main/resources/ 
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=my-registry.io/spark-test:test-3.0.0 
local:///var/service/my-service-6.3.0-RELEASE.jar
```

`spark-submit` successfully creates a pod in my k8s cluster. However, many of the config options I specified are not seen. For example, the pod does not have a volume mounted at `/var/service/src/main/resources/` despite the existence of a `persistentVolumeClaim` on the cluster called `my-pvc`. Further, the pod has not been given the specified image pull secret `my-cr-secret`, causing an `ImagePullBackOff` error. On the other hand, the pod *is* properly created in the `my-namespace` namespace and the pull policy `Always`.

I have attempted this using spark [3.0.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/running-on-kubernetes.html) and [2.4.5](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/running-on-kubernetes.html)

Why are some config options not reflected in the pod created on my cluster?

Comment: Did you checked if the secret exists and is correct, you can do that using `kubectl get secret my-cr-secret -oyaml`.

Comment: Yes, and the secret works in other pods that I manually created with a `deployment` as well

Comment: What is the image that `pod` is being started with?

Comment: `my-registry.io/spark-test:test-3.0.0`. Built with `./bin/docker-image-tool.sh`

Comment: Is the `pod` in `Running` state? You should check the events on that pod, why it's not working.

Comment: No, it's not running. As I mentioned the status is `ImagePullBackOff` because it doesn't have permission to pull the image from the repo without the secret in place

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209001/discussion-between-crou-and-mike-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue:

I currently have spark 2.3.1 installed locally and the variable `SPARK_HOME` points to `/usr/local/spark`. For this current project I downloaded a distribution of spark 2.4.5. I was in the 2.4.5 directory and running `bin/spark-submit`, which should have (as far as I can tell) pointed to the `spark-submit` bundled in 2.4.5. However, running `bin/spark-submit --version` revealed that the version being run was 2.3.1. The configurations that were being ignored in my question above were not available in 2.3.1.

Simply changing `SPARK_HOME` to the new directory fixed the issue